# Difference between uri_for and uri_for_action

Tags: perl, catalyst

What is the difference between `$c->uri_for` and `$c->uri_for_action` methods of Catalyst.

Which one to use? And why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found below difference between `$c->uri_for` and `$c->uri_for_action`

Consider

### Othercontroller.pm

```
__PACKAGE__->config(namespace => 'Hello');

.  
.   
.  

sub bar: Local{

$c->res->redirect($c->uri_for('yourcontroller/method_name'));

$c->res->redirect($c->uri_for_action('yourcontroller/method_name'));

}
```

### Yourcontroller.pm

```
sub method_name: Local{

print "In Yourcontroller:: method_name"

}
```

In case of `$c->uri_for` the url changes to

```
http://localhost:3000/Hello/yourcontroller/method_name
```

However for `$c->uri_for_action` the url changes to

```
 http://localhost:3000/yourcontroller/method_name
```

So the namespace gets added in case of `uri_for`.

Answer (score 5):

@Devendra I think your examples could be somehow misleading if someone reads them.

`uri_for` expects path (and not action). It return an absolute URI object, so for example it's useful for linking to static content or in case you don't expect your paths to change.

So for example, let say you've deployed your application on domain example.com and subdir abc (example.com/abc/): `$c->uri_for('/static/images/catalyst.png')` would return example.com/abc/static/images/catalyst.pn, or for example: `$c->uri_for('/contact-us-today')` would return example.com/abc/contact-us-today. If you decide later to deploy your application under another subdirectory or at / you'll still end up with correct links.

Let say that your contact-us action looks like: `sub contact :Path('/contact-us-today') :Args(0) {...}` and you decide later that /contact-us-today should become just /contact-us. If you've used `uri_for('/contact-us-today')` you'll need to find and change all lines which points to this url. However you can use `$c->uri_for_action('/controller/action_name')` which will return the correct url.

Comment: `uri_for` also works with action i.e. `$c->uri_for('/controller/action_name');` will also work.That's the issue actually.I couldn't find any difference between their (`uri_for` and `uri_for_action`) behavior/working except the `namespace`. Please check and reply.

Comment: Though you are right on the point about using `method_name` and not to match direct url.

Comment: Reading the docs seems like that :) I've just never used it like that. Sorry if I've confused you

Comment: `$c->uri_for_action` is only a small wrapper around `$c->uri_for` that fails if the path does not resolve to a known action. If the 1st argument is an Action object `$c->uri_for` is called anyway and can be used in the first place. You can find that in `lib/Catalyst.pm`.

Answer (score 4):

dpetrov_ in [#catalyst](http://irc.perl.org) says:

> If the paths are likely to change, [`uri_for_action`](http://p3rl.org/Catalyst#c-uri_for-path-args-query_values-) is better idea.